# I don't want to have to call custom function twice

Tags: javascript, html, css, knockout.js

I'm creating a `<li></li>` list where I loop through a list of **projects**, and if the project exist in **myProjects** I highlight that background.

I need to use this function twice, once for the background property and once for the border property. But to me it seems redundant having to run it twice, so is there a way to kind of return the object to the view and use it twice there? Or is there some other way around this?

Maybe this won't affect the loading time that much anyway?

**Model**

```
var vm = {
    myProjects: ko.observableArray(),
    projects: ko.observableArray(),
    inMyProjects: function (id) {
        var match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(vm.myProjects(), function (item) {
            return item.ProjectId() === id;
        });
        return match != null ? '#EEE' : '#777';
    }
};
```

**View**

```html
<ul class="projects" data-bind="foreach: projects">
    <li data-bind="text: Description, style: {
        backgroundColor: $parent.inMyProjects(ProjectId()),
        borderColor: $parent.inMyProjects(ProjectId())
    }">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `inMyProjects` return an object instead of the value and reuse the value in it:

var vm = {
        myProjects: ko.observableArray(),
        projects: ko.observableArray(),
        inMyProjects: function (id) {
            var match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(vm.myProjects(), function (item) {
                return item.ProjectId() === id;
            });
            var result = match != null ? '#EEE' : '#777';

```
    return {
        backgroundColor: result,
        borderColor: result
    };

    }
};
```

And then use it once in the view:

```
<ul class="projects" data-bind="foreach: projects">
    <li data-bind="text: Description, style: $parent.inMyProjects(ProjectId())">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Sorry, a bit in a hurry so there may be a typo but you get the point.

Comment: Oh, I kind of thought that should be possible. I searched for it but could't find anything on it.

Answer (score 0):

Don't rely on inline styling for things like this, introduce some CSS instead:

```css
.inMyProject {
    background-color: #...;
    border-color: #...;
}
```

You can then give your `li` element this class with [Knockout's CSS binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html):

```html
<li data-bind="css: { 'inMyProject': $parent.inMyProjects(ProjectId()) }">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`css`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/css-binding.html) binding with a class for both the background color and the border. `inMyProject`will be called only once.

Of course `inMyProject`should return a boolan now:

### JS

```
inMyProjects: function (id) {
    var match = ko.utils.arrayFirst(vm.myProjects(), function (item) {
        return item.ProjectId() === id;
    });
    return match != null;
}
```

### CSS:

```
projects li.in-my-projects {
    background-color: #EEE;
    border-color: #EEE;
}

projects li {
    background-color: #777;
    border-color: #777;
}
```

### HTML:

```
<ul class="projects" data-bind="foreach: projects">
    <li data-bind="text: Description, 
                   css: { 'in-my-projects': $parent.inMyProjects(ProjectId()) }
    }">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: CSS properties are hyphenated. `backgroundColor` should be `background-color` and `borderColor` should be `border-color`.